# $.ajax -> Eu estou perdido com esse erro "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Sinceramente, comecei faz pouco tempo nessa área, e eu tô perdido, não estou conseguindo entender porque esse erro continua.

Esse é meu HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="icon" type="favicon.png"/>

<script rsc="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script src="Script.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body onload="carregarCEP()">
    <section>
        <h1>Endereço Por CEP</h1>

        <h2></h2>

        <table id = "tabela"> 
            <caption>Agora Sim</caption>
            <thead>
                <th>cep</th>
                <th>address_type</th>
                <th>address_name</th>
                <th>address</th>
                <th>district</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>state</th>
                <th>lat</th>
                <th>lng</th>
                <th>city_ibge</th>
                <th>ddd</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu ajax.php está assim:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

O Erro ta aparecendo no  Script.js , logo na primeira linha, eu acho que deve ser alguma coisa com o meu ajax.php, mas eu não estou conseguindo evoluir nessa questão.

```
function carregarCEP (){    var iten="", url = "https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/54230120";   $.ajax({        url: url,       type: "GET",        cache: false,       dataType: 'json',       beforeSend: function(){             $("h2").html("Corregando");         },      error:function(){           $("h2").html("fonte de dados com problemas");       },      sucess: function(retorno){          if (retorno[0].erro) {
                $("h2").html(retorno.erro);             }           else{
                for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {
                    iten += "<tr>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].cep +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].address_type +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].address_name +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].address +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].district +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].city +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].state +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].lat +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].lng +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].city_ibge +"</td>";
                    iten += "<td>" + retorno[i].ddd +"</td>";
                    iten += "</tr>";

                }
                $("#tabela tbody").html(iten);
                $("h2").html("Carregado");          }       }   }) }
```

se for o caso, os senhores podem copiar o código e tentar rodar localmente pra entender melhor, mas de toda forma, segue o print do erro que aparece no meu console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez seja coisa "besta", mas eu tô perdidão.

Comment: O atributo rsc está errado, ao invés de `<script rsc="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>` deveria ser `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você colocou `<script rsc="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>` o correto é `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

O parametro da chamada do Script é **src** de "Source". É normal errar essas coisas no começo man. Bons estudos.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, depois que corrigir, o negócio andou melhor, ai depois o Clenir Santos deu uma força no comentário de baixo e agora as coisas já tão até correndo, kkkk muito obrigado cara, de coração , obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Altere a linha abaixo, mude o rsc, para src:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

E abaixo um modelo funcional do script:

```
function carregarCEP(){
            var url = 'https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/54230120';
            $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success : function(json){
                        if(json.cep){

                                $("#tabela tbody").html(json.cep);
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Meu Deus <o>, Melhorou muito meu código. agora é só arrumar algumas coisas internas e pronto, projeto terminado. Muito Obrigado <3